Why the integral of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ doesnt exist?
My math teacher told me that the integral of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is not possible but he didn't tell me the reason he just kept saying me to try on my own, well i want t0 know why is it not possible
I have just started calculus, please don't mind my question if wrong

Are you referring to an indefinite or definite integral?

an indefinite integral

Do you mean $1/\sin(x)$ or $\arcsin(x)$?

$$\int\sin^{-1}(x)dx=\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\sin^{-1}(x)+\text{constant}$$

There are some functions whose antiderivative is not expressible as a finite combination of some "nice" functions, but that doesn't mean the antiderivative doesn't exist. Both $\arcsin x$ and $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ have nice antiderivatives, though. You must have misunderstood what your teacher said.

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)}dx=\ln(\tan(x/2))+\text{constant}$$

Maybe your math teacher told you that the integral doesn't exist over an interval out of $[-1,1]$?

@AmitVerma Why don't just web search about it first ?
